# Break text in a div when the enter button is pressed

Tags: css

I am using this code to achieve the result of breaking the text in the enter button is pressed. It`s working perfectly, but I want to display the text in another page.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#input').keyup(function() {
     $('#output').html($(this).val()); 
   });
  });

 <textarea id="input"></textarea><br />
 <pre id="output" style="font-family: Arial";></pre>
```

How do I use `<pre id="output">` in another page? Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by another page ? after submitting form or other child window

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean taking the value of `input` and then putting it into a `<pre>` element in another file? You will need some server-side language for that, unless it's a child of the current window (for example an `iframe` element or modal window).

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this...but yes. I want to display the input value in another page

Comment: Lets say the form is on the product.php page, but I want to display the input on the index.php page

Comment: or is there a butter way to do this?

Comment: Submit the form on `product.php` to `index.php`, and then read the value of the field. You need to assign a name to the input element, though.

Comment: Yes, but when I read teh value of the field, I get just plain text but not the breaks from the input field.

Comment: The breaks are in the string, you just can't see them. Use `nl2br()`.

Comment: I want that when I press enter in the input field, I want it to be a line break when the text is displayed.

Comment: <?php echo nl2br($_POST['details']); ?> I echoed it in this way but did not work

Comment: Without more information, it's difficult to help further I'm afraid.